# Trigger to delete previous data on INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert

My table has the following columns: `type, how, what, index`

I need a trigger so when I insert a new record containing:

```
                      --TYPE--HOW--WHAT--INDEX--
INSERT INTO table VALUES(10, 'OP', 'IP', -1);
```

If there is already another record with `WHAT = 'IP'` then trigger should delete the previous record and continue inserting. Is this possible to do in `MySQL`?

I have tried to design my trigger using the Navicat but everytime I have ended with an exception showing up.

Comment: If WHAT is a unique key you could use INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...

Comment: @chrislondon That may be an option, but I'm not using the unique key on `WHAT` to prevent further errors as I can rely only on the MySQL side (cant modify the query or server-side C++ code because I dont have proper rights to do so).